# Openweathermap API on Githubpages

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, github-pages

I have a project I finished , and when you upload it on Github pages it doesn't work. It won't bring in any scripts, externally linked fonts, and API data. The API only supports HTTP, and Github pages only accepts HTTPS. Any way around it without changing API's?
The API is Openweathermap.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var temp = $('.temperature');
var APIKEY = ';
var loc = $('#search').val();
function updateByCity(loc){
 var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + loc + "&APPID=" + APIKEY;
 sendRequest(url);
}

function k2f(k){
return Math.round(k*(9/5)-459.67);
}
function ascii(a){
 return String.fromCharCode(a);
}

$('.enter').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var loc = $('#search').val();
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + loc + "&APPID=" + APIKEY;
 console.log(url);
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest ();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + loc + "&APPID=" + APIKEY;
  console.log("lol");
 var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
 var datatext = data.id;
 var name = data.name;
  var locname = name;
  var temptext = k2f(data.main.temp) + ascii(176) + "F";
  console.log(temp);
  console.log(url);
  $('.temperature').text(temptext);
 $('.city').text(name);
 };
 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xmlhttp.send();

});
```

Comment: You may not want to post your API key on SO.

Comment: Free API , but I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there won't be an easy way around this restriction as it is important for the security and integrity of your website. If you access resources from an HTTPS encrypted page via an unencrypted connection, the user will always see security warnings.

You could set up a proxy that accesses the API via HTTP and passes the calls on to the browser via HTTPS. Note that this may cause considerable overhead in terms of development effort.

The simplest solution would probably be to switch to a different weather data provider, [considering that HTTPS encryption by default may be a good idea](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/encrypt-in-transit/why-https).